# how can i add facebook webhook to any public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was able to add a web-hook to the page created by me using below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

But i  want to add web-hook to a few public pages to my app.

I tried asking one public page owner to add my app, so that i can see that page in my app and add webhook.
This did not worked.

Do i need to request for pageaccesstoken from page owners and subscribe?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes. The owner of the page needs to grant you a page access token

Comment: Thanks.I tried adding page subscription using below api./{page_id}/subscribed_apps.But still i am not able to get the page listed in the dropdown option where i can chose the pages which needs to be subscribed for my app using webhook.Do i also need to add the owner of the page as a user to my app.Any idea what i could be missing would be helful.

Comment: Actually I want to write a webhook to subscribe to any changes happening on a list of some public pages which are not owned or managed by me.Will i need to contact all this page owners and ask for page access token?Is there a programmatic way in which i can make request and get page access token from them.